# trying to set result of userservice into userscomponent

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created a UsersComponent which calls a UserService that returns a collection of users:

```
  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService
    .getUsers()
    .then(users => this.users = users)
  }
```

When my UsersComponent runs the code above, "undefined" is written to the console.  However, if I uncomment the extractData reference above then the response parameter in the function below has the user objects as expected:

```
extractData(response: Response) {
    this.users = response;
}
```

However in the runtime context of the function above, "this" is null so the code errors out. UsersComponent has a users variable of type User[] like this:

```
users: User[];
```

So what do I need to to in order to set the collection of user objects returned from the UserService to the users member variable of the UsersComponent?

Comment: Please provide code of userService Let us know you are using http service or with observable to get data

Answer (score 2):

change to

```
.then(users => console.log(this.users))
```

instead of

```
.then(console.log(this.users))
```

Comment: what you're suggesting just writes "undefined" to the console.  my main goal here is to set the user objects returned from the UserService to the users member variable of the UsersComponent

Comment: we can't just directly call console.log in "then". if you are still getting undefined then please try .then((users => { this.users = users; return users;}).bind(this))

Comment: there's no constraint preventing console.log() from then() statement. For example try .then(console.log('console log success'))